# iOS - Calling App Delegate method from ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

What I am trying to do is click a button (that was created in code) and have it call up a different view controller then have it run a function in the new view controller.

I know it could be done relatively easily in IB but that isn't an option.

An example of what I want to do would be if you had two view controllers one with a splash screen of house. The other view controller had a walk through of the house on it that you could go through all the rooms in a set order. The splash screen would have buttons for each room that would allow you to jump to any point on the walk through.

Answer (score 541, accepted):

You can access the delegate like this:

```
MainClass *appDelegate = (MainClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Replace *MainClass* with the name of your application class.

Then, provided you have a property for the other view controller, you can call something like:

```
[appDelegate.viewController someMethod];
```

Comment: might also need to import the appDelegate.h file wherever it is used, or do @class appDelegate

Comment: appDelegate.h file is a good candidate to go in the target's prefix/precompiled header file IMO.

Comment: If you import your app delegate in your Prefix.pch like @mharper says you can also add this at the same time: #define AppDelegate ((MyAppDelegateClass *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) which then allows you to access your app delegate like '[AppDelegate.viewController someMethod]'. It simplifies it a bit, but it also makes it easier to abuse it.

Comment: after the @end of my app delegate.h file , I added #define AppDelegate ((MyAppDelegateClass *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)  
Now whichever class imports app delegate can directly use 
[AppDelegate.viewController someMethod]

Answer (score 45):

And if anyone is wondering how to do this in `swift`:

```
if let myDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
   myDelegate.someMethod()
}
```

Comment: if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {} is a better approach in swift.

Comment: @petrsyn What do you mean the delegate can be `nil`? Isn't that an app ALWAYS has an AppDelegate?!

Comment: In recent versions of Swift, `sharedApplication()` should be replace with `shared`. i.e., remove "Application" and the parentheses. So the full working code as of Swift 5.2 would be:

`if let myDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
   myDelegate.someMethod()
}`

Answer (score 41):

Sounds like you just need a `UINavigationController` setup?

You can get the `AppDelegate` anywhere in the program via

```
YourAppDelegateName* blah = (YourAppDelegateName*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

In your app delegate you should have your navigation controller setup, either via IB or in code.

In code, assuming you've created your 'House overview' viewcontroller already it would be something like this in your `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`...

```
self.m_window = [[[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds] autorelease];
self.m_navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeViewController]autorelease];
[m_window addSubview:self.m_navigationController.view];
```

After this you just need a viewcontroller per 'room' and invoke the following when a button click event is picked up...

```
YourAppDelegateName* blah = (YourAppDelegateName*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[blah.m_navigationController pushViewController:newRoomViewController animated:YES];
```

I've not tested the above code so forgive any syntax errors but hope the pseudo code is of help...

Comment: Your answer is correct as well, I ended up using a combination of Cristian's and your answer. I wish I could split the check mark.

Answer (score 18):

This is how I do it.

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] performSelector:@selector(nameofMethod)];
```

Dont forget to import.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Answer (score 13):

Just Follow these steps

1.import your app delegate in your class where you want app delegate object.

```
#import "YourAppDelegate.h"
```

2.inside your class create an instance of your app delegate object(Its basically a singleton).

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate=( YourAppDelegate* )[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

3.Now invoke method using selector

```
if([appDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(yourMethod)]){

        [appDelegate yourMethod];
    }
```

or directly by

```
[appDelegate yourMethod];
```

for swift

```
let appdel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

i will recommend the first one. Run and Go.

Comment: this is specifically NOT a new instance of the delegate, but rather retrieves the singleton delegate of the singleton application

Answer (score 11):

```
NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> * universalAppDelegate = 
    ( NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> * ) [ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] delegate ];
```

It avoid having to include your AppDelegate.h everywhere. 
It's a simple cast that goes a long way, allowing to develop independent Controller and reuse them elsewhere without to worry about class name and so on...

Enjoy

Comment: Thank you for sharing, it makes me happy for a couple of minutes, probobly it'll work some way, but what if I want to use a method like visibleViewController from it? It'll give error like this: Property 'visibleViewController' not found on object of type 'NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate> *. any solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

A lot of good answers are already added. Though I want to add something which suits me most of the time.

```
#define kAppDelegate ((YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]);
```

and thats it. Use it throughout the application just like a constant.

e.g.

```
[kAppDelegate methodName];
```

Don't forget to import yourAppDelegate.h in corresponding .pch or macros file.

Answer (score 7):

If someone need the same in Xamarin (Xamarin.ios / Monotouch), this worked for me:

```
var myDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
```

(Require using UIKit;)

Comment: The correct statement in Swift is 
let appdel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

Answer (score 6):

**Update for Swift 3.0 and higher**

```
//
// Step 1:- Create a method in AppDelegate.swift
//
func someMethodInAppDelegate() {

    print("someMethodInAppDelegate called")
}
```

calling above method from your controller by followings

```
//
// Step 2:- Getting a reference to the AppDelegate & calling the require method...
//
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {

    appDelegate.someMethodInAppDelegate()
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

And in case you need access to your WatchKit extension delegate from a view controller on watchOS:

```
extDelegate = WKExtension.sharedExtension().delegate as WKExtensionDelegate?
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `#define uAppDelegate (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` in your project's `Prefix.pch` file and then call any method of your `AppDelegate` in any `UIViewController` with the below code.

```
[uAppDelegate showLoginView];
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, iOS13, xCode 11.3. What is working for Objective-C is:

`#import "AppDelegate.h"`

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

It's working for me, i hope the same to you!  :D

Answer (score 0):

Even if technically feasible, is NOT a good approach.
When You say: "The splash screen would have buttons for each room that would allow you to jump to any point on the walk through."
So you want to pass through appdelegate to call these controllers via tohc events on buttons?

This approach does not follow Apple guidelines and has a lot of drawbacks.

Comment: Look at the date on the question... It's from back when Interface Builder was a separate application and development was a very different beast. I haven't touched iOS development in years so I can't evaluate more modern answers.

Comment: it ca be.. but my considerations are still valid