# UITabBarController in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible and if so how can I use the UITabBarController in a class other than the appdelegate class?

Comment: You can use it the same way like an ordinary viewController because tabBarController is inherited from it. Doesn't it work?

Comment: could you say what do you want accomplish so I could be more specific in my answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `UITabBarController` is inheriting `UIViewController`, you can use it like a normal `UIViewController`, outside of `AppDelegate` class. The question is what you are trying to accomplish. For instance, you can present `UITabBarController` modally or push it to the screen using `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Here is what i am doing: I create a new class and select tabbarcontroller as the superclass and it gives me 3 new files .h .m .xib, then i drag a uitabbarcontroller onto the screen and wire it up but when i run the app i only see the blank view. I do not see the tabbarcontroller i added???

Comment: a little more info. I am using a uinavigation controller as my root view controller

Comment: A UITabBarController can't be a child view controller of another view controller, according to Apple's documentation. So you can't push a UITabBarController on to a UINavigationController. You can however have a UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController. You could also present a UITabBarController modally like you said in your answer.

Comment: Ok let me explain a little more. I have a sliding drawer that slides left and right. The navigation controller is on the main drawer which has a tab bar controller on it. I set the navbar controller + the tabbar controller in the appdelegate. However when i slide to the left i would like to add another tabbar controller to the bottom of that view. Is that possible or too many different controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a `UITabBarController` defined in `AppDelegate`. If you really want to do sth with that tab bar in other class (for example `UIViewController`) you can access `AppDelegate` like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

and then via property or methods you can access this tab bar. [More examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082738/ios-calling-app-delegate-method-from-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out how to fix it. I simply added a uitabbarcontroller programmatically vs IB and all is well. Thanks for the responses!