# Call Javascript from Phonegap outside of Plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, cordova

I'm new to PhoneGap/Cordova, and would like to call some javascript outside of the CDVPlugin interface.... In code that isn't part of a plugin.

Is this possible? If I could get a reference to the webview that PhoneGap uses, I should be able to call something like:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myJSFunction()"];
```

or

```
[super writeJavascript::@"myJSFunction()"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this for ios by getting a reference to the WebView from the AppDelegate:

```
+(void) fireJavascript:(NSString*) javascript
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [appDelegate fireJavascript:javascript];
}
```

and in your AppDelegate, define a method like so:

```
- (void) fireJavascript:(NSString *)javascript
{
    NSLog(@"About to fire js:%@", javascript);
    [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
}
```

Note that you can get a reference for the app delegate in your app [using info from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082738/ios-calling-app-delegate-method-from-viewcontroller) on StackOverflow.