# How to share data between number of ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I know one way to share data is segue. But in my application I have multiple tabs which contain number of VCs. For instance `userName` and `address`. I want to show in some of the VCs these infos. 
Every time I query the cloud is not right way. I am following this answer first part: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1125364/1679519). But as a newbie I am not sure how `MyDataModel` is defined. Is it a NSObject class? I appreciate if anyone can define this class as example with two `NSString` fields. And how to access these fields in VC and AppDelegate.

**Inside AppDelegate**

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{

    MyDataModel *model;
    AViewController *aViewController;
    BViewController *bViewController;
    ...
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet AViewController *aViewController;
@property (retain) IBOutlet BViewController *aViewController;

@end

@implementation MyAppDelegate

...

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
...

    aViewController.model = model;

    bViewController.model = model;

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

**Inside VC:**

```
@interface AViewController : UIViewController {
    MyDataModel *model;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyDataModel *model;

@end

@interface BViewController : UIViewController {
    MyDataModel *model;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyDataModel *model;

@end
```

The only thing I need is where to define `MyDataMode` and how to access its fields?

Comment: Create a SubClass of NSObject, and in .h file, create '@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *str1;' '@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *str2;'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use singleton class for that,

```
----------
SharedManages.h
----------

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

@interface SharedManager : NSObject
{

}
+(SharedManager *)sharedInstance;

// Create property of your object which you want to access from whole over project.

@property (retain, nonatomic) User *loginUser;
@property (assign, readwrite) BOOL isNetAvailable;

@end

----------

----------
SharedManages.m
----------

#import "SharedManager.h"

static SharedManager *objSharedManager;

@implementation SharedManager

@synthesize
isNetAvailable  = _isNetAvailable,
loginUser    = _ loginUser;

+(SharedManager *)sharedInstance
{
    if(objSharedManager == nil)
    {
        objSharedManager = [[SharedManager alloc] init];
        objSharedManager. loginUser = [User alloc]] init];

        Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
        NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
        // Bool

        if(internetStatus == NotReachable)
        {
            NSLog(@"Internet Disconnected");
            objSharedManager.isNetAvailable = NO;  // Internet not Connected
        }
        else if (internetStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
        {
            NSLog(@"Connected via WIFI");
            objSharedManager.isNetAvailable = YES; // Connected via WIFI
        }
        else if (internetStatus == ReachableViaWWAN)
        {
            NSLog(@"Connected via WWAN");
            objSharedManager.isNetAvailable = YES; // Connected via WWAN
        }

    }

    return objSharedManager;
}


@end
```

Access from other Class...

```
[SharedManager sharedInstance].isNetAvailable ;

[SharedManager sharedInstance].loginUser ;
```

Hope, This will help you..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. so you mean SharedManages in my question is equal to SharedManages. I need all those setting plus what you have given here or just this class?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have "local" copies of the values. I set them in the delegate and fetch them from there. That way you don't have to hard code it for all `UIViewController`'s in the delegate.

Assigning values is best done on the first view, or with default values. I personally use viewDidLoad for those kind of things. Since it is only called once on the first view once and pertains until the app is terminated.

Then I get the delegate from inside the VC, call the instance and from there the values.

Swift

Inside AppDelegate:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var globals : GlobalValueClass?
```

First VC:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        delegate.globals = GlobalValueClass()
        delegate.globals!.numbers = [1,2,3]
    }
}
```

Other VC's:

```
class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        print(delegate.globals!.numbers)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Objective C ( don't have the full method in obj-c, but easy to find)

```
MainClass *appDelegate = (MainClass *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

[how to get the delegate in obj-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082738/ios-calling-app-delegate-method-from-viewcontroller)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way i could think of is using `NSUserDefaults`. Save your `name` and `address` string in `NSUserDefaults` like

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:YourNameString forKey:@"NameString"];
[defaults setValue:YourAddressString forKey:@"AddressString"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

and access it in any `ViewController` as

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *name = [plistContent valueForKey:@"NameString"];
 NSString *address= [plistContent valueForKey:@"AddressString"];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class and use it in your tab controller.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>



@interface UserModel : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;

+ (instancetype)modelObjectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryRepresentation;

@end
```

implementation file

```
#import "UserModel.h"


NSString *const kUserModelLastName = @"LastName";
NSString *const kUserModelFirstName = @"FirstName";


@interface UserModel ()

- (id)objectOrNilForKey:(id)aKey fromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;

@end

@implementation UserModel

@synthesize lastName = _lastName;
@synthesize firstName = _firstName;


+ (instancetype)modelObjectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
}

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    self = [super init];

    // This check serves to make sure that a non-NSDictionary object
    // passed into the model class doesn't break the parsing.
    if(self && [dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            self.lastName = [self objectOrNilForKey:kUserModelLastName fromDictionary:dict];
            self.firstName = [self objectOrNilForKey:kUserModelFirstName fromDictionary:dict];

    }

    return self;

}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryRepresentation
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [mutableDict setValue:self.lastName forKey:kUserModelLastName];
    [mutableDict setValue:self.firstName forKey:kUserModelFirstName];

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutableDict];
}

- (NSString *)description 
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self dictionaryRepresentation]];
}

#pragma mark - Helper Method
- (id)objectOrNilForKey:(id)aKey fromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    id object = [dict objectForKey:aKey];
    return [object isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? nil : object;
}


#pragma mark - NSCoding Methods

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];

    self.lastName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kUserModelLastName];
    self.firstName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kUserModelFirstName];
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{

    [aCoder encodeObject:_lastName forKey:kUserModelLastName];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_firstName forKey:kUserModelFirstName];
}
```

Import this class where you are setting or initializing data or values. and do below code.

```
    NSDictionary *dicUserModel = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Moure",@"LastName",@"Jackson",@"FirstName", nil];

    UserModel *userModel = [[UserModel alloc]initWithDictionary:dicUserModel];
    //NSUserDefault save your class with all property. and you can simply retrieve your UserModel from NSUserDefault.
    //Below code save this model into nsuserdefault.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:userModel] forKey:@"UserModel"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

You can retrieve you class object using below code.

```
    UserModel *savedUserModel = (UserModel *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"UserModel"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",savedUserModel.firstName);
    NSLog(@"%@",savedUserModel.lastName);
```