# iOS Switch between 2 Navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

In my app, if the user isn't logged, it shows a login controller which is embedded in a navigation controller.
When the user is logged, the app should switch to the other navigation controller to display the app.

How can I switch from one navigation controller to another one when the user is logged. ?

Thanks

[image]

I'm checking if the user is log in app delegate :

```
 // Check if user is log
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    if currentUser != nil {
        // Do stuff with the user
    } else {
        // Show the signup or login screen
        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nav = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LogInController") as! UINavigationController
        self.window?.rootViewController = nav
    }
```

**SOLUTION : looks like it works**
When user press logIn button :

```
let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nav = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainNavController") as! UINavigationController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
```

Comment: where do u decide if user is logged in or not ? App delegate ? view did load ?

Comment: yes in app delegate. code edited.

Comment: you can change to other navigation controller too, use storyboard ID !!!

Comment: when user is log by pressing the log button, I can't make self.window.rootViewController because i'm not in the app delegate now but in the logInViewController

Comment: u can use the app delegate any where in your view controllers. Just the pass the reference of app delegate to your view controller!!!!

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082738/ios-calling-app-delegate-method-from-viewcontroller

Comment: thank you seem it works. Can I add transition when switching the navigation controller ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94873/discussion-between-user3722523-and-mr-t).

Comment: Ofcourse You can!!!! If the transition doesn't work.....you can try adding the UIVisualEffect!!!!

Answer (score 7):

#### Solution 1

One solution would be to use just a single navigation controller. When the user logs in, you would pop all the view controllers used for logging in and push main view controller on the stack.

#### Solution 2

Alternatively, you could present a new navigation controller modally on top of the login stuff, with main controller as its root. It would be simply presented on top of it.

#### Solution 3

You can also consider creating the navigation controller with main view controller first and presenting the login navigation controller on top of it. Then, when user logs in you would just dismiss the login navigation controller revealing the main view controller.

Comment: Wouldn't solution 1 involve a glitch after you pop the login VCs and before pushing the main VC? We have a similar problem but with the added twist of the second nav controller (i.e., flow) needing a different orientation from the first nav controller.

Answer (score 4):

Set your navigation controller storyboard ID

```
    let navigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondNavigationController")
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: then how u dismiss it ?

Comment: U mean when u want to log out ? Btw u can also use nsuserdefaults to check login