# How to call an AppDelegate method from a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my *appDelegate.m* file I have this method

```
- (void) goToRN {
   [RCTKeyWindow().rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}
```

and I would like to call this method from my *ConsentViewController.swift* file like: `AppDelegate().goToRN()`

but I'm getting this error: `Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'goToRN'`

Comment: Actually, i answered too fast. This question duplicates this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082738/ios-calling-app-delegate-method-from-viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the application global variable :

```
NSApp.delegate
```